# アロー関数式のreturn文にセミコロンが付加されているために発生するエラー

Tags: javascript

()の内部が「アロー関数式」かつ「return文にセミコロンがある」場合、ar.map()はArray [2, 3, 4]を表示しませんでした。 この問題の原因または誤りを指摘できますか？

```
function f1(x){return x+1;}
const ar = [1,2,3];
console.log(ar.map(/* ... */));
```

|  | x => ~ ; | x => ~ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f1(x) | Error: missing ) after argument list | Array [2, 3, 4] |
| x+1 | Error: missing ) after argument list | Array [2, 3, 4] |

|  | function(x){return ~;} | function(x){return ~} |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f1(x) | Array [2, 3, 4] | Array [2, 3, 4] |
| x+1 | Array [2, 3, 4] | Array [2, 3, 4] |

Answer (score 2):

`map`の引数としてアロー関数式の一つの形

```
param => expression
```

を使うならば、`;`は余計です。式 (expression) に`;`は含まれません。

`;`は 文 (statement) を構成します。
たとえば

```
expression ;
```

は文 (statement) です。

文には本来 `;` が必要ですが、JavaScriptのセミコロン自動挿入機能により、多くの構文で、文の `;` を省略することが可能となっています。だからセミコロンの無い文

```
return expression
```

もエラーとならずに済んでいるわけです。

Comment: callbackにセミコロンを付けようとしていたのは、セミコロンを(アロー関数中の)return文というstatementの終了を示す記号として認識していたからです。ここに誤解があったのだと推測しています。
もし誤解だというのが正しいとすると「let f1 = x => x + 1;; console.log(f1(1));」のエラーが出ない点に疑問は残りますが。

Comment: 「let f1 = x => x + 1;; console.log(f1(1));」

これは
「let f1 = x => x + 1;」
というlet宣言と
「;」
「console.log(f1(1));」
という2つの文です。（１つ目は空文です）。
最初のlet宣言は
「let var = value ;」
の形を使用しています。そしてvalueとして 「x => x + 1」というアロー関数式の一つの形を使用しています。
構文上、何も疑問の余地はありません。

Comment: 回答者は、「let f1 = x => x + 1;; console.log(f1(1));」を、「let f1 = x => x + 1」「」「 console.log(f1(1))」の3つのstatementから構成されていると指摘していますか?

Comment: 回答者とは私のことですか？
そしてあなたは誰ですか？
質問の意図がわかりませんが、何を知りたいのですか？

Comment: 私は十分明確に質問者の疑問に答えたつもりですが、それでも理解できないのならこちらをしっかり読み込むことをお勧めします。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: 47480/ゲストは、45045/Itagaki Fumihikoに対して、45045/Itagaki Fumihikoの書いたコメントを正しく解釈しているかどうかを確認しているだけです。